# How to route subdomains to one or more appropriate nodes within a cluster?

Tags: java, jetty, subdomain, distributed-computing

I am trying to solve a distributed computing architecture problem. Here is the scenario.

Users come to my website and registers. As a part of the registration process they get a subdomain. For example, foo.xyz.com.

Now each users website is located/replicated on a one or more cluster nodes using some arbitrary scheme.

When the user request comes in (HTTP request via browser) , appropriate subdomain must be redirected to the matching cluster node. Essentially, I want my own dynamic domain name. I need to implement it in a fast and efficient way.

I've a java based web application which runs inside a Jetty7 container.

thanks,

NG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely should be implemented outside of your application. Your Web application should be, as much as possible, agnostic from the way that requests get balanced in a cluster. The best performance you would get would be with hardware load balancers [this one for example](http://www.barracudanetworks.com/ns/products/balancer_overview.php).

If you want to go for software based balancing I would configure Apache to serve as entry point and balance the traffic for your cluster with something like mod_proxy. [See this tutorial that refers to Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+mod_proxy).

Comment: I just stumbled across [Apache Traffic Server] (http://trafficserver.apache.org/). Looks like an industrial strength server for doing reverse proxying.

Answer (score 0):

have you taken a look at Nginx?Nginx may be more than your needs but it does effective job of routing subdomains to particular nodes.